# GitHub Pages adding html and/or local links to a .md file

Tags: html, markdown, github-pages

Given some .md markdown

```
# Coronavirus[1](#1), 
etiam nominatum virus coroniforme, est summa virorum biologicorum qui virus ARN sunt.

1. Origo nominis est vocabulum "corona" ea ratione, quod forma eius externa similitudinem habet solis vel ornamenti capitis regalis.
```

The goal is [1] to be a link to "1.". 
It works on preview when setting the bottom element as Html element

```
<div id=1> ...</div>
```

however when published on GitHub pages

```
<div id=1> ...</div>
```

is not recognized. It seems it's possible to include Html but just without attributes.

What options do I have to achieve this while keeping the main part of the document as Markdown
(both pure Markdown or mixed with HTML is ok)?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075663/markdown-how-to-reference-an-item-in-a-numbered-list-by-number-like-latexs

Comment: Thanks the second answer does the job:
"Maybe you need to use the H1.. H6 and then Markdown generates an anchor that you can link to:" ...