# Numbered list cross reference in Markdown

Tags: markdown, markdown-it

I there any way to reference a specific item in ordered list?

I mean something like:

---

1. some item
2. another item explaining something
3. a third item.

As explained in (2) above...

---

I don't need the actual link, just be able to reference the generated number.
Of course I need something stable if I insert/remove items, otherwise automatic numbering is useless (if I need referencing).

I am aware of an [old Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37075663/1714490) which seems to imply this is not possible; is it still the case? Even with CommonMark or extensions?

Comment: maybe take a look at https://lierdakil.github.io/pandoc-crossref/ ?

Comment: No, there is nothing like this in Markdown. Some tools add extra features, but without knowing which one you're using we can't help much.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks, I am using VitePress which relies on [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) to render Markdown. It seems to have zillions plugins, but I'm unsure if there's something I can actually use. I have full control of VitePess instance, so I *can* add plugins if useful.